# excel-vba opening old file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have been maintaining the various set lists for my band in Excel manually. I decided to write a nice VBA front end to make it easier. Since the setlist excel file is shared on my dropbox for all the band memners and sound team, i copied the setlist.xlsx to newsetlist.xlsm while writing the code. After "finishing" the code, I archived the original setlist.xlsx file and renamed newsetlist.xlsm to setlist.xlsm.

However, now when I launch the first userform, for some reason, Excel tries to open mewsetlist.xlsm which of course, no longer exists. I've searched through all of the code and can't find anywhere that I explicitly try to open newsetlist.xlsm. In fact, the vba code has aways run under the assumption that the workbook was aready opened.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Might want to post your code. If you recorded some macros, the name might be hard coded in there somewhere.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet button which could be linked to the original file?

Comment: If Edit/Find "newsetlist", run from the VBE window ("Find whole word only" disabled), doesn't find the name in the "Current project", then there is indeed no mention of that name in the code - neither explicit nor implicit. Therefore the mention must be in the worksheet(s). Start by looking in the formulas there, then look at links (Get External Data, on the Data tab). Yes, also look at ActiveX controls on the sheets as already suggested above.

Comment: It could also be something in a defined name. Use the Name Manager on the Formulas tab of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I had two lines of code in Module 2 of the workbook. The first called a sub that looked for a worksheet named "Blank" which I use to build my sets, renaming it when I'm done. This just cleans up any remnants of unfinished work by deleting it if it's there. The second line put up the master userform. I had placed that macro on the quickaccess toolbar. It was clicking on that which caused Excel to go after the old file name.

Well, I added a new module and wrote a new sub, copied and pasted those two lines into it, removed the old macro from the quickaccess toolbar, put the new one on there and presto, it no longer tries to open the old file. All I can figure is, Excel had somehow associated the old name of the file in macro icon on the quickaccess toolbar. Probably just needed to remove that macro from the toolbar and re-add it in the new file.

Just because you asked, here's the code.

Now in module 3:
sub setManagementStartup

```
Call delBlankSheet

MasterScreen.Show
```

end sub
Public Sub delBlankSheet()

```
Dim blankExists As Boolean

blankExists = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If ws.Name = "Blank" Then
        blankExists = True
    End If

Next ws

If blankExists Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blank").Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If
```

End Sub